# “Few programmers are aware of the fact that a class's constructors and methods can run prior to its initialization”

Tags: java, initialization

In the official Java guide [“Programming with assertions”](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) it is stated that
(last paragraph on the page)

> Few programmers are aware of the fact that a class's constructors and methods can run prior to its initialization. When this happens, it is quite likely that the class's invariants have not yet been established, which can cause serious and subtle bugs.

What is meant by this? When does this happen? Is it something I have to care about in my daily use of Java?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Basically, they talk about the following situation:

```
public class Foo {
    public static Foo INSTANCE = new Foo(); // Prints null

    public static String s = "bar";

    public Foo() {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

As you can see, in this case constructor runs before initializer of the static field `s`, i. e. prior to the full initialization of the class. It's just a simple example, but it can become more complex when multiple classes are involved.

It's not something you can often see in your everyday work, but you need to be aware of this possibility and avoid it when writing code.

Answer (score 5):

As an example, consider virtual method dispatch in a constructor.

```
class Foo {
   Foo() {
      int a = bar();        
      b = 7;
   }

   private int b;

   protected int baz() { assert b == 7; return b; } ;

   protected abstract int bar();
}
```

If a subclass happened to call `baz` from within their implementation of `bar` they'd hit the assertion.  The object hasn't finished construction so the `Foo` base class is in a bit of a state.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they mean the logical initialization. For example your class A has method `init()` that must be called before using of any business methods. But other programmer that uses this class has not read manual and wrote `new A().foo()`. Probably in this case `foo()` cannot work correctly. In this case assertion may be useful. You can check in the beginning that `init()` was not called and throw assertion.

The same is with constructors. This may happen when somebody extends your class A:

```
class B extends A {
    B() {
        foo(); // init() must be called before foo!
    }
}
```

Comment: what is logical initialization (in contrast to just initialization)?